# Monitor Postfix outgoing mail delivery

Tags: linux, display, smtp, postfix, syslog

I'm using GNU Mailman with Postfix to run a mailing list, and would like to monitor the delivery of outgoing mail, that is: for each mail sent from the list, check whether a 250 (OK) message was answered, and if not, report back to me.

For now, I'm doing a quick-and-dirty:

```
# cat /var/log/syslog | grep "smtp.*to=.*" | grep -v 250
```

Is there a clean way to monitor smtpd's output?

Comment: Surely this must be a [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)? At the very least you can do `grep "smtp.*to=.*" /var/log/syslog | grep -v 250`

Comment: Personally I find that crusade a bit pedantic in most contexts and prefer the OP's more readable, modular format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to monitor the sent mails in a clean way. You can only grep the details from the maillog of postfix.

Here is an example:

```
log='logfile of postfix'
grep "status=sent" $log | \
egrep -ve 'postfix/(cleanup|pickup|master|qmgr|smtpd|local|pipe)'
```

And also avoid the logs for `dkim` etc. If you need the count of mails then pipe on `wc -l` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
multitail -eX "smtp.*to=<(.*)>.*sent.*250" './bin/received' -f /var/log/maillog
```

./bin/received is a shell script that gets the destination email address as a parameter and does something with it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
cat /var/log/maillog |grep -v "relay=local" |grep "relay=" |grep "status=sent"
```

you will find very helpful info here http://en.redinskala.com/postfix-maillog-interpretation/

Comment: Why are you using smart quotes? They won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pflogsumm`](http://jimsun.linxnet.com/postfix_contrib.html) to get an overview of entries in the logs:

```
cat /var/log/mail.log | pflogsumm 

Grand Totals
------------
messages

     26   received
     25   delivered
      0   forwarded
      0   deferred
      2   bounced
      0   rejected (0%)
      0   reject warnings
      0   held
      0   discarded (0%)

    752k  bytes received
    751k  bytes delivered
     14   senders
      7   sending hosts/domains
      3   recipients
      3   recipient hosts/domains


Per-Day Traffic Summary
-----------------------
    date          received  delivered   deferred    bounced     rejected
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    May  7 2023         7          7 
    May  8 2023        11         10          0          2 
    May  9 2023         8          8
```

Another option is [Lightmeter](https://lightmeter.io/) which is able to notify you when something happens, although I cannot recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I am watching who sends email through my server with this:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log | grep 'sasl'
```

It shows who the authenticated user is who's sending.

Answer (score 0):

Note that other information than the 250 can still be relevant to what constituted a successful delivery.

For example a successfully sent message that was marked as spam **could** have a message looking like this:

```
... status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK DMARC:Quarantine ...)
```